# Delegate method is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c

The problem is a delegate method is not called.
I have this code.

GridView.h

```
#import "EditViewController.h"

@protocol GridViewDelegate<NSObject>
- (void)didSelectCell:(UIView *)cell index:(NSUInteger)index;
@end

@interface GridView : UIView<EditViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<GridViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

GridView.m

```
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"handleTap!");
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectCell:index:)])
    {
        [self.delegate didSelectCell:gestureRecognizer.view index:0];
    }
}
```

MainViewController.h

```
#import "EditViewController.h"
#import "GridView.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController<GridViewDelegate>
```

MainViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view addSubview:gridView];

    GridView *gridView = [[GridView alloc]init];
    gridView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didSelectCell:(UIView *)cell index:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"Success!");
}
```

When this app build,
`handleTap` method is called, but `self.delegate didSelectCell` is not called.

When `didSelectCell` method is described in GridView.m, NSLog correctly outputs `Success!`

how do I fix it to call delegate method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view addSubview:gridView];

    GridView *gridView = [[GridView alloc]init];
    gridView.delegate = self;
}
```

after adding the grid view to the view, you create a new grid view.
 Therefor you have two grid views: one is added to the view, one has a delegate.

get rid of

```
GridView *gridView = [[GridView alloc]init];
```